# Il(s) existe(nt?) plusieurs solutions

Tags: accord, conjugaison, pronoms-impersonnels

Quand on utilise la construction

> Il existe x tel que ...

comment est-ce qu'on fait les accords si x est pluriel ? Écrit-on

> Il existent des idées..

ou

> Il existe des idées... ?

Comment: Qu'est-ce que vous feriez à un autre temps ? *il existera des idées nouvelles* (ok), *ils existeront des idées nouvelles* (très étrange)...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Le *il* dans *il existe* (avec un sens proche de *il y a*) est un pronom impersonnel, comme dans *il pleut* ou *il faut*. Il ne fait référence à aucune entité. Il occupe le rôle de sujet parce rien d'autre n'est là pour l'assurer.

Il n'est dans ce cas pas possible de le remplacer par un pronom pluriel ni de conjuger au pluriel.

> Il existe des êtres vivants capables de résister à de telles températures.

*Exister* peut néanmoins être utilisé d'une façon differente:

> Ces animaux existent.
>
> Plusieurs possibilités existent.

Il faut alors bien sûr conjuger le verbe correctement.

Answer (score 5):

En français, le verbe s'accorde toujours avec son sujet.

Voici l'exemple d'une phrase typique:

> Je mange une pomme.
>   [Je] **(Sujet)** [mange] **(verbe)** [une pomme] **(complément)**.

Le verbe *manger* vient s'accorder avec son sujet (*je*) : `Je mange`.

Cela aurait pu être :

> **Je mange** des pommes.
>   **Nous mangions** une tarte.
>   **Ils mangent** leur repas.
>   Etc.

Ainsi, on peut déduire que pour ta phrase, la bonne façon de l'écrire est :

> Il **existe** des idées. (*existe* s'accorde avec *il*) (Doit être au singulier)

Dans ce cas, *il* est impersonnel, *il* ne remplace rien. Comme dans la phrase :

> **Il** pleut (*Il* est impersonnel) (Doit être au singulier)

Au lieu de laisser le sujet impersonnel (*il*), nous pourrions aussi dire :

> Des idées **existent**. (*exister* s'accorde avec *Des idées*)
>   Elles **existent**. (*exister* s'accorde avec *Elles*, remplançant *Des idées*)

Comment: Qu'est-ce que veut dire : *le verbe se conjugue toujours avec son sujet* ? Tous les verbes conjugués n'ont pas un sujet exprimé, notamment les impératifs et il est sans doute plutôt question d'accord avec le sujet que de conjugaison avec le sujet, ici ?

Comment: @GAMPUB , j'ai corrigé mon *typo* pour conjugue/accorde. L'impératif s'accorde quand même avec son sujet, dans ce cas un sujet intrinsèque. Par exemple, la phrase `Mangez!` implique le sujet *Vous* même s'il est absent.

Answer (score 0):

salut; Il faut écrire "il existe", avec accord avec "il".

Comment: Bienvenu à French.SE :). Peux-tu essayer d'inclure une explication à ta réponse? S'il pose la question, c'est probablement pour comprendre la raison de cet accord.

Comment: Please elaborate more your answer. Thank you

Comment: But if the **sole** issue here concerned according/conjugating the verb with the subject then wouldn’t simply pluralizing “il” resolve it: “Il**s** existent …” ?  Adding at least a passing reference to the fact that **both** “**il**” and “existe” in the “il existe” construction in this context must be singular would make this a complete answer that would get my upvote. (cc: @hunter )