# Transitivité du verbe "exister"

Tags: verbes, transitivité

Dans tous les dictionnaires que j'ai consulté, le verbe "exister" est signalé comme intransitif, et s'utilise pour signifier l'existence du sujet, par exemple:

> Je pense donc j'existe.
>
> Pourquoi de tels monstres existent-ils ?

Pourtant j'ai remarqué que certain l'utilisaient comme un verbe impersonnel:

> Il existe deux solutions à ce problème.

Cette utilisation est-elle correcte ? Si oui quelles sont ses limites ? Peut-on par exemple dire : "Je pense donc il n'existe pas moi" ? (ce qui me parait très bizarre comme formulation)

Comment: Une question assez proche de celle-ci : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16917/ils-existent-plusieurs-solutions

Comment: Pour la formulation : *Je pense, donc il existe un 'moi'* (que je peux formuler). *Je pense donc il n'existe pas de moi réel* (en fait je crois penser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Exister* n'est pas un verbe transitif, il n'admet pas de COD.**

L'emploi "il existe ..." est une forme **impersonnelle**, qui se forme avec des **verbes d'état, ou de changement d'état** comme *exister* (verbes qui indiquent soit la présence ou l'existence d'une chose, soit son arrivée, sa survenue):

L'emploi se fait à la **troisième personne du singulier**, même si le véritable sujet est au pluriel.

Cette construction **n'est pas possible avec un pronom**, comme demandé dans la question: *Il existe moi*. Elle est suivie d'un groupe nominal.

Verbes d'état:

> Il apparaît des nuages = des nuages apparaissent.
>
> Il transparaît un problème = un problème transparaît.
>
> Il reste des points à traiter.
>
> Il demeure quelques difficultés.

Autres formes:

> Il faut une idée = une idée est nécessaire.
>
> Il suffit d'une idée = une idée suffit.
>
> Il est des questions délicates.
>
> Il y a ..., Il arrive ..., Il survient ..., Il advient ...
>
> Il manque un ingrédient = un ingrédient manque.
>
> Il coule de la confiture = de la confiture coule.
>
> Il tombe de la neige = de la neige tombe.
>
> Il pleut des ennuis = des ennuis pleuvent.

un lien: [francaisfacile](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-102007.php)

Une exception au non-emploi des pronoms: on peut employer des pronoms indéfinis (pas tous):

> Il arrive tout, n'importe quoi.
>
> Il apparaît autrui.
>
> Il arrive quelque chose.
>
> Il n'arrive rien.
>
> Il n'arrive personne.

Voir sur [Wikipedia les pronoms indéfinis et locutions pronominales indéfinies.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronom_ind%C3%A9fini)

Comment: Le "groupe nominal" qui suit le verbe d'état n'est-il pas un COD ? (il tombe quoi ? de la neige)

Comment: Verbes d'état et forme impersonnelle n'ont pas de lien que je sache. Aucun de ces verbes (y compris *exister*) n'est un verbe d'état. Tu as des exemples dans lesquels ils sont utilisés avec un attribut ? Veux-tu dire que leur forme impersonnelle est assimilable à un verbe d'état (j'ai du mal à voir pourquoi) ?

Comment: Autrement, remarquer qu'une tournure impersonnelle ne peut être utilisée avec un pronom semble très pertinent. Je ne trouve pas de véritable contre-exemple, seulement des cas limites comme « il tombe de tout ».

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez certains verbes d'état peuvent être utilisées sous forme impersonnelle: paraître, apparaître, être.

Comment: En effet certains appartiennent aux deux catégories.

Answer (score 2):

"Il existe" est couramment utilisé en France sous la forme impersonnelle, suivi d'un COD:

> Dans ce monde, **il existe** 10 types d'Hommes, ceux qui savent compter en binaire, et ceux qui ne savent pas.

La proposition "Je pense donc il n'existe pas moi" est incorrecte. Mais on pourrait dire :

> Je pense donc il n'existe pas **de** moi

Cela implique qu'on insiste sur "un moi", qui semble donc philosophique.
Je ne pense pas qu'il existe de limite à l'utilisation impersonnelle, pour aider à construire la phrase, on peut ajouter "Dans ce monde", pour dire "il existe dans ce monde [...]" ou "Dans ce monde, il existe [...]"

Pour la forme négative, "il existe" est toujours suivit de "de" s'il y a un complement:

> (Dans ce monde,) il n'existe pas **d'** éléphants volants
>   il n'existe pas **de** poulemouth.
>   [...]

Par contre, en utilisant la forme personnelle, on ne met pas de "de":

> Les monstres n'existent pas

Comment: mais pourquoi "Je pense donc il n'existe pas moi" est incorrecte si il n'y a pas de limite à l'utilisation impersonnelle? Cela devrait être correct dans ce cas.

Comment: @AnneAunyme j'ajoute un commentaire, cela vient de la forme négative

Answer (score 1):

Certaines phrases se prêtent plus à l'utilisation de la forme impersonnelle, d'autres à la forme intransitive.

La construction impersonnelle est normalement suivie d'un complément qui confère à l'entité en question un caractère plus remarquable, ou tout du moins différent des autres.

> Il existe des chats qui ont peur des souris.
>
> Il existe des jours plus appréciables que d'autres.
>
> Il existe un moyen efficace de s'en débarrasser.

Une phrase qui utilise « il existe » suivi d'un groupe nominal (sujet réel) mais sans complément/attribut du sujet réel n'est pas une phrase habituelle. On ne dit généralement pas « Il existe des chats » mais plutôt « Les chats existent ». Bien que cela arrive parfois, comme dans « Il existe des solutions », mais il y a une sorte de sous-entendu : « qui fonctionnent ».

Réciproquement, le sujet de la forme transitive est rarement caractérisé, sinon pour préciser sa nature. L'existence est plus fondamentale et n'est pas caractérisée parmi d'autres.

> Ce risque de contamination existe.
>
> N'oublie pas que j'existe.
>
> Ce problème n'existe pas.

Comment: @Anne: Éviter cette tournure ? Penses-tu vraiment que ça pourrait être « incorrect » comme prétendu dans la question ? Je te souhaite un bon courage, il y a des centaines de milliers de livres à « corriger »… https://www.google.com/search?q=%22il+existe+des%22&tbm=bks

Answer (score 1):

**Il y a.** Tout d'abord, ça ne semble pas un emploi inhabituel, [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/exister/32149/locution) note « Il existe quelqu'un, quelque chose, synonyme de il y a : *Il n'existe pas de solution à votre problème.* ». Le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/exister) confirme : « − *Par extension* (sens atténué). Être, se trouver; *en particulier* tournure impersonnelle *il existe* « il y a ». ». Nous sommes dans la rubrique A.2 et ce qui est atténué est : « Courant [Assorti de coordonnées (espace, temps) et de modalités précises] Être dans la réalité, au monde. ». Quelques [rubriques](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue) sur le site de l'*Académie* emploient *il existe*. La section [étymologie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/exister) au TLFi pour exister est plutôt brève ; on dit « être actuellement » 15<sup>e</sup>, 1760 « vivre ».

**Hors de + être placé**. Le DHLF dit du latin *sortir de*/*se manifester*, *se montrer* ; courant au 16<sup>e</sup> avec le complément de lieu, dans le sens de *se trouver dans un lieu*, vaut aussi pour *se trouver à un moment donné* ; puis 17<sup>e</sup> pour *avoir une réalité* qui était rare avant ce moment ; 18<sup>e</sup> pour *vivre*, et *avoir de la valeur pour* etc. (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, dir. A. Rey, aux ed. Le Robert). On a non seulement le synonyme d'un emploi impersonnel (*il y a*), mais aussi l'évolution du verbe *exister* s'appuie-t-elle sur la sémantique de verbes dont l'emploi est *pronominal*. On observe que *il existe* diffère uniquement de *il y a* comme [*morphème de présentation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avoir) par l'absence du pronom *y* qui a de toutes façons essentiellement perdu sa valeur locative (LBU14). En langue littéraire on peut souvent utiliser [*il est* + nom](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre/31549/locution) au lieu d'*il y a*, sauf quand ce dernier représente une durée, une distance (LBU14). Que le verbe soit généralement intransitif n'empêche pas l'emploi ou le mode impersonnel ici, et il s'agit d'une locution davantage figée où l'analyse du pronom et du sens est souvent peu fructueuse. Il peut arriver qu'avec une phrase particulière on oscille entre une lecture de la sémantique d'*exister* par opposition à une simple construction synonyme de *il y a*. Sans doute que plus *il existe* (et sans doute *il y a*) se détache du contexte de la *présentation* (comme en début de phrase), et a fortiori si on altère le mode du verbe et les pronoms en remaniant, plus il paraîtra inusité, la locution s'étant simplement étiolée, à mon avis...

---

R: Premièrement, Oui. Deuxièmement, je dirais que la limite est l'intégrité morphologique (la position du pronom etc.) et syntaxique (la position souvent en début de phrase), mais je n'ai pas l'expertise pour l'étayer. Enfin, je *dirais* que la négation ne va pas dans le sens de l'idée de présentation (...de l'absence ?) et qu'elle l'affaiblit. *Il n'y a pas (une, d', ...) armée qui puisse m'en empêcher* est-elle si étrange sans déterminant, n'est-ce pas *aucune* que cela au final ? *Je pense donc n'existe aucun moi* ? Le *moi* y est [substantivé](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/moi/52006?q=moi#51880) et sa fonction est donc différente, le tout peut-être ambigu à souhait, quoiqu'on aime bien...